# Find index of first element of last group regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I have the following problem: I have a collection of strings who look kinda like this:

```
"01100110011"
"11100110010"
"10001110000"
```

Could there be written a regex that finds the index of the first one in the last group of ones? I am currently using  hashmaps and lots of  calculations related to lastindexof indexof etc. But at this point it's starting to look ridiculous.

Comment: You'll need to elaborate a bit on "the index of the first one in the last group of ones?" and post the relevant part of your code, stating what's not working.

Comment: Everything's working with my code, however i dont want to use my 100 lines method for such a simple task. I however cant seem to get the regex for it right. And what i mean by the first one in the last group of ones is that for example here : 01100110011 the last group of ones is the two ones at the end of the string. I need the index of the one at the start of the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple, compile the following regex and search for the first match with `Matcher.find()`:

```
".*(?<!1)(1)"
```

You can get the index by calling `.start(1)` on the `Matcher` object.

The regex basically finds the last `1`, which is not immediately preceded by another 1 `(?<!1)`, which effectively finds the first one in the last group of consecutive 1's.

Sample code:

```
int startingIndexOfLastGroup(String str) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(?<!1)(1)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    if (m.find()) {
        return m.start(1);
    }

    // Return -1 for a string without 1
    return -1;
}
```

The regex above is simple, but not very nice, since it backtracks quite a bit. If you don't want too much backtracking, you can use the following regex:

```
"(?:[^1]*+(1+))*+"
```

Simply put, it will search for 0 or more of non-1 characters `[^1]*+`, followed by one or more of `1`'s `(1+)`, and such sequence repeated as many times as possible. Since a repeated capturing group only stores the index of the last capture, it will effective record the start index of the last group of consecutive `1`'s.